# Custom port names for netstat

Tags: netstat

Whe I use the `netstat -l` command I get the port names, and when I add the `-n` param I will get the port numbers.

There is a way to set custom names to other ports?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can add new ports with new descriptions to the `/etc/services` file, and in fact, can change the name of existing ports (however, I don't know what kind of grief that may cause, if any).

Just be sure to use the same line syntax when adding new ports, and I'd recommend keeping them all in numerical order.